# Add attributes to element inside string

Tags: javascript

I have a list of attribute in object that I want to add as attribute to an element inside the string:

```js
var ob_attr = {
  type: 'button',
  'data-action': 'send',
  class: 'sendmessage'
};
var BC = "<div class='col-lg-6'><button>Send</button></div>";
$(BC).find('button').attr(ob_attr);

    //output
    console.log(BC);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The console still look like the value of variable BC

I want the output to look like:

```
<div class='col-lg-6'><buton class='sendmessage' data-action='send', type='button'>Send</button></div>
```

Comment: I've put your code in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so that it's runnable here, and if you click on Run code snippet, you'll see there's a syntax error.

Comment: I was missing quotation mark closing....$(BC).find('button')... so i've fixed that but what i want to achieve is not this.

Comment: Note that you're logging the *string* `BC` again, not the *element* created from `BC`. `console.log($(BC).find('button').attr(ob_attr).html())` is a closer approximation to what you want.

Comment: var elemBC = $(BC).find(...... console.log(elemBC)

Comment: @aconsuegra please what is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Why not just write the attributes into your string? Are you trying to automate this for multiple uses with different attributes?

Comment: @bitox. NO because in my real code am looping through var ob_atttr which is coming from the server as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that the string somehow becomes the HTML element. It stays a string. You need to reference the elements you create.

```js
var ob_attr = {
  type: 'button',
  'data-action': 'send',
  class: 'sendmessage'
};
var BC = "<div class='col-lg-6'><button>Send</button></div>";
var elemBC = $(BC)
elemBC.find('button').attr(ob_attr);

//output
console.log(elemBC.html());
console.log(elemBC[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a string to insert by doing this

```
var newStr = 'button'
for (const attr in ob_attr) {
  newStr += ` ${attr}="${ob_attr[attr]}"`;
}
```

and then add the new string like this

```
BC.replace('button', newStr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Using 
BC.getelementsbytagname('button').setattribute(property,value)
in the same manner give all the attributes